# Taking an integer and splitting it into multiple rows in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integer, row

Is there a way to take an integer and turn it into multiple rows based on that integer?

So, for example, to take this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'StringColumn': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                   'Integer_Column': [5,3,4],
                   'Integer_Column2': [3,2,1]})
```

| String | Integer | Integer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 3 |
| B | 3 | 2 |
| C | 4 | 1 |

And change it to:

| String | Integer | Integer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 0 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 1 |
| C | 1 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 0 |
| C | 1 | 0 |

I found how to aggregate integers together and group it to a column but not splitting it like this.

Comment: Is the max number always in the first Integer column?

Answer (score 2):

You can duplicate the rows with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)+[`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html), then assign 1 or 1 depending on the comparison with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
(df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Integer_Column'])]
   .assign(Integer_Column=1,
           Integer_Column2=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount().lt(d['Integer_Column2']).astype(int))
 )
```

Output:

```
  StringColumn  Integer_Column  Integer_Column2
0            A               1                1
0            A               1                1
0            A               1                1
0            A               1                0
0            A               1                0
1            B               1                1
1            B               1                1
1            B               1                0
2            C               1                1
2            C               1                0
2            C               1                0
2            C               1                0
```

##### alternative

If there can be more integer columns and the max per row is not always in the first Integer column:

```
(df.set_index('StringColumn')
   .loc[lambda d: d.index.repeat(d.max(axis=1))]
   .pipe(lambda d: d.gt(d.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), axis=0).astype(int))
   .reset_index()
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(df[['StringColumn']].join(df.select_dtypes(include = np.number)
.applymap(lambda x: [1]*x)
.stack()
.explode()
.to_frame()
.assign(cc = lambda x: x.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount())
.set_index('cc',append=True)[0]
.unstack(level=1)
.fillna(0)
.reset_index(level=1,drop=True)))
```

Output:

```
  StringColumn  Integer_Column  Integer_Column2
0            A               1                1
0            A               1                1
0            A               1                1
0            A               1                0
0            A               1                0
1            B               1                1
1            B               1                1
1            B               1                0
2            C               1                1
2            C               1                0
2            C               1                0
2            C               1                0
```